# Combining multiple regressions into one table in R

Tags: r, stargazer

I am testing the importance of 25 different dummy variables using 5 different models in R. I want to test each dummy variable separately to all other dummies, which means running each model 25 times. I would like to create a table where each column would be one of the five models, and each dummy variable outcome would be a row. Ideally hoping to do this with stargazer, what is the best way to code it. Because the constant, and each of the controls is slightly different depending on the dummy variables it insists on putting each run as its own column, I am happy to lose the constant and control info from the table.

So far I have tried variations on this where m1 is a list of all linear models

stargazer(m1, m2, m3, type="text", title="Regression Results", single.row=FALSE,  ci.level=0.9, multicolumn=TRUE,omit.stat ="all" )

have tried different inputs around multicolumn, omitting.stats, etc

Thanks so much

Comment: hi,
your are more likely to get an answer if you present what you tried so far.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to do this above